GRUB fails to load Windows Boot Manager upon selection
I currently have Fedora 41 and Windows 11 installed on separate drives, but I'm having issues adding the Windows Boot Manager to the GRUB boot interface.
Running sudo os-prober shows the Windows Boot Manager is identified, even without mounting anything, returning /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi:Windows Boot Manager:Windows:efi and when I ran sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg (even after mounting the Windows EFI) it says Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/nvme0n1p1@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi. But when I restart and select Windows Boot Manager in the GRUB interface, nothing happens. The interface effectively resets, and then when I select Fedora 41 I am unable to load Fedora and the following error is displayed:
error: ../../grub-core/fs/fshelp.c:257:file `/vmlinuz-6.11.0-63.fc41.x86_64' not found
error: ../../grub-core/loader/i386/efi/linux.c:258:you need to load the kernel first.

Pressing escape and then entering exit in the GRUB terminal boots Windows normally, and if I restart and select Fedora 41 without trying to load Windows I am able to successfully boot Fedora. As far as I know, fast start and bitlocker encryption are both disabled. Any idea what might be going wrong here and how I can get this working properly?

Grub only boots working Windows. You should be able to boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. But Windows fast startup, which sets hibernation flag preventing the Linux NTFS driver from fully seeing NTFS, must be off. And Windows must not need chkdsk. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

So for some context, fast startup is disabled, and I had earlier installed Fedora with systemd-boot and that bootloader was able to detect and load Windows without issue. Yes, I can boot Windows from the UEFI menu but I find that a bit more annoying having to time key presses properly as opposed to the GRUB menu which displays at boot. I seem to be able to mount my Windows boot partition from within Fedora without issue. I'll check the hibernation setting but this seems to be specifically a GRUB issue?

I have never used systemD boot, but that replaces grub. So did you do a full reinstall of grub?

Yeah, this was a complete reinstall of Fedora and Windows 11 on separate drives. Fedora by default uses Grub but there’s a boot setting in the installer one can edit to install systemd-boot instead. But as far as I know the process of getting sdboot to comply with secure boot is kind of a pain and after a mobo update scrambled my loaders I went back to Grub in my fresh install.

Windows is known to turn fast startup back on with updates which you may not see. And even update UEFI firmware resetting it to defaults. Not familiar with Fedora's version of grub or those errors.
